# Why is there a difference in the output of setof between facts with a different amount of elements?

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof

In Prolog, given a knowledge base of facts:

```
someFact(one).
someFact(two).
otherFact(one, two, 123, 456).
otherFact(one, four, 789, 123).
```

The query `setof(X, someFact(X), List).` produces this result:

```
List = [one, two]
```

However, the query `setof(X, otherFact(one, X,_,_), List` produces this:

```
List = [two]
```

While I expected it to produce `[two,four]`. Using [this](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse1) source I discovered that typing `;` when the first list is returned will show all the other options:

```
List = [two] ;
List = [four] .
```

Why does it do this? Is it because of the underscores? How do I produce a set where both `two` and `four` is given, without pressing `;`? 
I didn't know how to find an answer to this as I have trouble phrasing this problem into a question that produces search results

Comment: Rule-of-thumb: `_` and `setof/3` don't flock together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write:
`setof(X, B^A^otherFact(one, X,A,B), List)`.

Querying:

```
?- setof(X, B^A^otherFact(one, X,A,B), List).
   List = [four,two].
```

That's because even if you place `_` in `setof(X, B^A^otherFact(one, X,_,_)` , **setof/3** is designed to search all free variables. By placing `B^A^` in front you choose not to bind either  A or B and search only other variables.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @coder's answer you could write using `library(lambda)`:

```
?- setof(X, X+\otherFact(one,X,_,_), List).
```